# Oracle SQL: How to Achieve This?

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

I have two columns in a CSV file with entries like:

```
Column Admin            Column Action
Admin                   Read
                        Write
                        Delete 
Custodian               Read
                        Write  
User                    Read
```

The requirement is to have an SQL query which displays the data like:

```
Column Admin            Column Action
Admin                   Read
Admin                   Write
Admin                   Delete
Custodian               Read
Custodian               Write
User                    Read
```

I am looking to achieve this without the use of regexp. The Column `Action` can contain any entry and not specific to just Read/Write/Delete.

Comment: You would like to have a SQL query for CSV file?

Comment: Yes. I am using HXXT TEXT Drivers to have most of the SQL queries run on a CSV file

Comment: Without a column that indicates at which order those lines are imported this looks impossible.  If it had such a column you could do something with the LAG or LEAD functions. Maybe if you show the code how you import that file then it could be changed in the loop that processes line by line.

Comment: @LukStorms Since the rows are in a csv not a database, the order is implicit in the data.

Comment: Where are the CSV strings in your sample input? What you show doesn't match what you are saying/asking.